# Minimal distance between random points on the unit circle

Tags: pr.probability

Fix $n$. Take the integers from $0$ to $n-1$ and define the distance between $x, y \in [0, n-1] \cap \mathbb{Z}$ as $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|, n- |x-y|)$.

Now take $2k$ distinct points $x_1, \dots, x_{2k}$ in $[0, n-1] \cap \mathbb{Z}$.

What is the probability
$$P(\cap_{1 \leq i < j \leq 2k}  ( d(x_i, x_j)  > k )),$$
that is, the probability that the distance between any two points $x_i \neq x_j$ is bigger than $k$?

Clearly, if $k^2 > n/2$, by pidgeonhole the probability above is zero.

I am mainly interested in lower bounds for big $n, k$, or references if the answer is known.

Answer (score 3):

Consider two configuration to be equal if they just differ by a rotation or addition modulo $n$ in your notation. You can define a bijection between the configurations of the 2k points on $[0,n-1]$ with pairwise distance larger than $k$ and the configurations of 2k points on $[0,n-2k^2-1]$ with pairwise distance larger than $0$ by deleting $k$ elements between any two neighbors. Hence the probability is
$$\frac{\frac{(n-2k^2)!}{(n-2k^2-2k)!}\frac{n}{n-2k^2}}{n^k}=\frac{(n-2k^2-1)!}{n^{k-1}(n-2k^2-2k)!}.$$